# Why is this question Opinion-Based?

Tags: discussion

I am talking about [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/33107/is-the-flat-earth-society-for-real).

I have the same question. Actually by asking whether this society is real or not and whether their members honestly believe their claims involves at least one of them:

- They hold a regular agenda regarding their topics.
- They perform some kind of actual activism (e.g. trying to plunge their ideas into the educational system).
- They actually sell or distribute material actively promoting their claims, and try to fit somehow (unsuccessfully) in a kind of debate or academic circle.

In this context, what I can infer is that *honestly* means doing something in their agenda beyond a website (of which we could not infer anything regarding the honesty).

Actually I don't know how to answer the question, since I have the same, and would like an answer for it, just for curiosity.

Is there a way this question be reopened? E.g. one of:

- Could the moderator review the question according to this question?
- How could the question be reworded to make it fit the site rules?

Answer (score 2):

Because we don't allow questions on other people beliefs. See [Politics, beliefs and motivations questions should not be allowed here.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here) for further info.

"Do its members honestly believe its claims?" is not a question that can be answered with facts, which is why the question is opinion-based, and why the rule exists in the first place.

I can see that there's a part of the question which is, instead, factual: "Does the society exist?". Restricting the question to it will fix the question, but it would be quite different from the original intentions of the asker, so it's up to them to fix it

Comment: I don't see how the body of this answer satisfies anything more than just the title of the question. Additionally, if what I understood regarding the involved question is the intended spirit of the OP, then the quoted link in the answer does not apply to the quoted question in my question.

Comment: I don't get your point. We don't allow questions on beliefs. The question is explicitly and literally about beliefs. Thus the closure. If you disagree with the site rule, please take this discussion to the linked meta question. If you disagree that the question asks about motivations and beliefs, then ...I don't know how to explain it better. The question openly asks about them.

Comment: The question finisher is *Does the society exist and do its members honestly believe its claims?*. The OP is not questioning their belief but their... existence. You are the author of the linked question in your response, but no matter how you argue here, no case in your question or in the answer reflects the reason of the closure.

Comment: PLEASE: to be clear just add a case like this to the question you wrote, since after reading your question, Shog's answer, and the answer after Shog's answer, no case fits like this, and it is better if stuff gets clear. The FlatEarth question has participation in comments, which is not dismissive but participative. This makes me think that not enough people takes your point as well I don't. The best you could do is add this example case to the rule-question you posted here.

Comment: I am trying to understand better what is unclear to you. "Do its members honestly believe its claims?" is not a question that can be answered with facts, which is why the question is opinion-based, and why the rule exists in the first place. I can see that there's a part of the question which is, instead, factual: "Does the society exist?". Restricting the question to it will fix the question, but it would be quite different from the original intentions of the asker, so it's up to them to fix it.

Comment: Thanks :D That addresses the second alternative ("How could the question be reworded to make it fit the site rules?"). I can accept the answer if you append your last comment to your answer.