# Questions that ask about polling in totalitarian/authoritarian countries

Tags: discussion, scope

Related to Qs like [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/do-donetsk-residents-want-to-join-russia). I'm pretty sure I can [find](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/sep/19/xi-jinping-does-china-truly-love-big-daddy-xi-or-fear-him) [some](https://www.refworld.org/docid/570f425312.html) piece of propaganda that says that [almost] everyone in China adores Xi Jinping as their president, and likewise for North Korea or even Eritrea. Are questions like "is this true?" on-topic here, given how difficult it would be answer them with a real poll? (I somewhat haphazardly came up with that list, but it [turns out](https://cpj.org/reports/2019/09/10-most-censored-eritrea-north-korea-turkmenistan-journalist/) I hit 3 of the top 5 "most censored countries", according to CPJ.)

Comment: How is that any different from YouGov polls or the BBC?

Answer (score 1):

The question itself is answerable - as in, there is a theoretical possibility of  independently-sourced data existing that proves or disproves official press releases. And even if such data doesn't exist - explanation of why existing data isn't enough to be a proof either way [can also be a good answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/should-we-ask-questions-that-dont-have-answers).